# How to include header file in main file in the View Folder using php Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure

I have two folder in View Folder

1. Layout Folder :- in this folder I have create two files header.php and footer.php
2. Agent Folder :- In this folder iIhave Main file dashboard.php.

I want to include header and footer file from layout folder to Dashboard.php.

I am using this code:

```
<?php include('../layout/header.php') ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->load->view('layout/header');
$this->load->view('layout/footer');
```

In controller function just load using this code:

```
public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('layout/header');
            $this->load->view('agent/dashboard');
            $this->load->view('layout/footer');
    }
```

Comment: but I want to include these files in dashboard.php

Comment: you mean in view file , right? Try this it will be work.

Comment: Thanks, It's work. But i have dout , how it works if i load in this sequence
$this->load->view('layout/header');
$this->load->view('layout/footer');
$this->load->view('admin/dashboard.php');

how can it automatically identify where is add header,footer in dashboard ?

Comment: Read codeigniter documentation properly. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 1):

Folder structure

application/view/template 
application/view/site

```
$this->load->view('template/header');
$this->load->view('site/dashboard');
$this->load->view('template/footer');
```